# c# NUnit Test disappear after copy local set to false

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a solution with several projects. 
I have a test project that references other projects.

If I set all the references to copy local to true then the tests show up in the test explorer window. If I set all references to copy local to false then the tests disappear from the text explorer.

How do I fix this, or is this suppose to happen and I need to set copy local to true in order for unit test to show up?

Edit:
In the output this shows up

> NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
>
> Dependent Assembly nunit.framework, Version=2.6.3.13283, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77 of (solution
>   folder)(project folder)\bin\x86\Debug(testfile).dll not found. Can be
>   ignored if not a NUnit project.

But if I browse to the folder the dll is there

Comment: To find the tests, the discoverer needs to reflect over the assembly, so if there is a problem loading the fixtures because some dependent assemblies cannot be found then yes you may be missing them in the Test Explorer. Is there anything in the output window under Tests that indicates that there was a problem loading the tests?

Comment: @mikez
Here is what it says NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
Dependent Assembly nunit.framework, Version=2.6.3.13283, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77 of (solution folder)\(project folder)\bin\x86\Debug\(testfile).dll not found. Can be ignored if not a NUnit project.
But the test dll is there if I browse to the directory

Comment: It's the nunit.framework.dll that cannot be found, not the test dll. I see the same thing if I set copy local to false for nunit.framework.dll, so the solution is to set copy local to true for nunit.framework.dll.

Comment: Okay I've set the nunit.framework.dll to copy local to true and re build. It gives the same error and it does not show up in the test explorer